# Analytical method to show decreasing sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]
Suppose $a_1=\frac12$  and  $a_{n+1}=\frac16+a_n^2$. It is easy to show that it converges to $\frac{1-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}}{2}$.

I wrote a MatLab program  to make sense of it. My question is: how does one show that the it is a decreasing sequence analytically?

Comment: You can show it by induction, I think

Comment: yes, induction is the best way.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $a_n - a_{n+1} = - a_n^2 + a_n - 1/6 > 0$ if $(1-\sqrt{1/3})/2 < a_n < (1+\sqrt{1/3})/2$, where the endpoints are the roots of the polynomial $-t^2 + t - 1/6$.

Now you need to show $a_n$ stays in this interval.

Answer (score 3):

$$a_2 =\frac16+\frac14=\frac5{12}<\frac12=a_1$$

Assume $a_k \geq a_{k+1}$.

Consider $$a_{k+2}=\frac16+a_{k+1}^2\leq\frac16+a_k^2=a_{k+1}$$

Therefore, by induction the given sequence is decreasing.

Comment: :how can I assume that $a_k \geq a_{k+1}$ ?

Comment: Induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is $$a_1=\frac12,\\a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac16+a_n^2-a_n$$

For it to be decreasing, we must have

$$a_n^2-a_n+\frac16<0$$ or, by solving the quadratic inequation,

$$\frac{3-\sqrt3}{6}<a_n<\frac{3+\sqrt3}{6}.$$

If this condition is achieved, then for then next iterate we have

$$\left(\frac{3-\sqrt3}{6}\right)^2+\frac16<a_{n+1}=a_n^2+\frac16<\left(\frac{3+\sqrt3}{6}\right)^2+\frac16.$$

As you can check, this is strictly

$$\frac{3-\sqrt3}{6}<a_{n+1}<\frac{3+\sqrt3}{6},$$ and the condition obviously holds for $a_1$.